# File download : Spring - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, download

I am working on file download where my front end is AngularJS and backend a spring controller

```
downloadResponse.success(function(response){
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

                    var file = new Blob([ response ], {
                        type : 'application/octet-stream',
                    });
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    var a         = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href        = fileURL; 
                    a.target      = '_blank';
                    a.download    = fileName;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }).error(function(response){
                    console.log("Error");
                });
            };
```

Call to the Spring Controller

```
downloadFile:function(loggedId, fileId, fileName){
            var downloadFileURL = "/downloadFile";
            var formData = $.param({ "loggedId" : loggedId, "fileId" : fileId, "fileName": fileName});

            return $http.post(downloadFileURL,formData, {headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}}, {responseType:"arraybuffer"});
        }
```

Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadFile")
public void downloadFile(@RequestBody String msgBody, @RequestParam(value = "loggedId") String loggedId, @RequestParam(value = "fileId") String fileId, @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {       
    byte[] bytes = downloadFile(loggedId, fileId, fileName, request, response);
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);

/* InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
IOUtils.copy(in, fos); */ ---- I am able to download the file from the Spring controller
}
```

I am able to download the file with contents from Spring Controller but facing issues while passing it to angular. I am getting a empty pdf file. Text files are downloaded properly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1 : I can see something like this in the browser Response but not sure why an empty file is created

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
612 0 obj
<</Linearized 1
/L 979975
/H [ 10681 506 ]
/O 614
/E 149424
/N 60
/T 967590
>>
endobj
    xref
612 497
0000000015 00000 n 
0000010395 00000 n 
0000011187 00000 n 
0000011411 00000 n 
0000011562 00000 n 
0000011779 00000 n 
0000011928 00000 n 
0000012154 00000 n 
0000012389 00000 n 
0000012523 00000 n 
0000012760 00000 n 
0000012941 00000 n 
0000013123 00000 n 
0000013353 00000 n
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're performing a POST for the download?

Comment: No. I am just doing a POST request to my spring controller.

Comment: I guess the POST makes sense if you alter the server status. Instead, it seems like you just want to GET the resource..

Comment: I need to add the server status as well. Was trying to get this work first :)

Comment: @Sheetal, have you tried to send real content type from server (and use it later in your blob), like `application/pdf`, for example, instead of `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: Yes Leffchik. I have tried with both application/pdf and octet-stream. Both dint work. Not sure what could be going wrong

Comment: The PDF-Content you show above seems corrupted. It should end with %%EOF.

Comment: Yes, data ends with "
>>
startxref
175
%%EOF" .   I dint paste the whole thing as it was large amount of data

Comment: Ok, so the pdf seems correct. It should be a problem in the controller logic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe angular don't trust your file. Please try to inject $sce (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) into your angular controller and then call

```
url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url)
```

on your url before you write it into a.href.

And i think the pdf content is available in response.data and not response itself.

```
var file = new Blob(response.data, {
   type : 'application/octet-stream',
});
```

Comment: Schuller Thank you. But this dint help, I am still getting a empty file

Comment: Do you set the response from $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url) to url again? I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Ok, I tried as mentioned "fileURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);" but no luck yet

Comment: I tried with response.data. It now says the PDF is either damaged or corrupted :(

Comment: Did you also remove the brackets around response.data? I think it has to be new Blob(response.data, {type: 'application/octed-stream'}).

Comment: Yes, that dint work either. When I print response.data its undefined

Comment: Another try with new Blob(response, {type: 'application/octed-stream'}) without brackets?

Comment: Last attempt: Do you have to set the stringified value to blob? var doc = JSON.stringify(response); new Blob([doc], ...

Comment: File is damaged with JSON.stringify